# How to not setting a computed variable value in set function if condition is not satisfied

Tags: vue.js, buefy

The question is pretty simple: I've a computed property with setter and getter. It return a data property but I want set the value only if certain conditions are respected.
In the example that you can find [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-yj8ug?from-embed) I'm only setting the value if a year is greater or lower than another one.
E.g.: if you set the value in the first combobox greater than the second one I should expect no update since I'm not setting the variable but, as you can see, the property is updated.
Any suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In your setters you're using the stored values for the comparison instead of the new value. So, instead of this ..

```
// selectedYearAfter
set(selectedYearAfter) {
        if (this.selectedYearBefore < this.selectedYearAfter) {
                // do stuff
        } else {
               // should set nothing
        }
}
```

You should do this ..

```
// selectedYearAfter
set(newValue) {
        if (this.selectedYearBefore < newValue) {
                // do stuff
        } else {
               // should set nothing
        }
}
```

This should fix the issue of getting the correct values of `selectedYearBefore` and `selectedYearAfter`.

If you want the view to reflect these internal values you should provide [keys](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) for your comoboboxes and update the keys in your setters. This will provide a hint for Vue to update the view when you want it to reflect the internal state ..

```
<b-field>
  <b-select :key="comboBoxKeys.key1" v-model="selectedYearBefore">
    <option v-for="year in years" :key="`${ year }-after`" :value="year">{{ year }}</option>
  </b-select>
</b-field>
<b-field>
  <b-select :key="comboBoxKeys.key2" v-model="selectedYearAfter">
    <option v-for="year in years" :key="`${ year }-after`" :value="year">{{ year }}</option>
  </b-select>
</b-field>
```

Example code below ..

```js
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      selectedYearBefore_: 2008,
      selectedYearAfter_: 2010,
      comboBoxKeys: {
        key1: this.getKey(),
        key2: this.getKey()
      },
      years: [
        1994,
        1998,
        2000,
        2002,
        2004,
        2006,
        2008,
        2010,
        2012,
        2014,
        2016,
        2018,
        2020
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getKey() {
      return Date.now();
    }
  },
  computed: {
    selectedYearAfter: {
      get() {
        return this.selectedYearAfter_;
      },
      set(newValue) {
        if (this.selectedYearBefore < newValue) {
          this.selectedYearAfter_ = newValue;
        } else {
          console.log("Should set nothing");
          this.comboBoxKeys.key2 = this.getKey();
        }
      }
    },
    selectedYearBefore: {
      get() {
        return this.selectedYearBefore_;
      },
      set(newValue) {
        if (newValue < this.selectedYearAfter) {
          this.selectedYearBefore_ = newValue;
        } else {
          console.log("Should set nothing");
          this.comboBoxKeys.key1 = this.getKey();
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<template>
  <section>
    <b-field>
      <b-select :key="comboBoxKeys.key1" v-model="selectedYearBefore">
        <option v-for="year in years" :key="`${ year }-after`" :value="year">{{ year }}</option>
      </b-select>
    </b-field>
    <b-field>
      <b-select :key="comboBoxKeys.key2" v-model="selectedYearAfter">
        <option v-for="year in years" :key="`${ year }-after`" :value="year">{{ year }}</option>
      </b-select>
    </b-field>
  </section>
</template>
```

I'm using a timestamp as the key to force the view to update when needed, but you can use any value you like instead.

[image: Edit Vue Template]

Comment: Right, I copy paste to fast but your solution is not working also in your sandbox. Try your cose before post as solution

Comment: @Tinwor Sorry I thought you only meant to fix the internal value. If you want the view to update as well and prevent the comboboxes from changing you can add a `key` as a hint to force the view to update. I'll edit my answer shortly.